# How do I exit a function cascade/chain?

Tags: javascript, chaining

If you create an object with functions that return `this`, you can create a chain of functions that were called previously and create a cascade of function calls:

```
var i = {
  foo: function () {
    // Something here...
    return this;
  },

  bar: function () {
    // Something here...
    return this;
  }
};

i.foo().bar().foo()
```

But what if an error occurs in `bar` and I don't want to call `foo` in that case? How do I break the cascade?

If it is at all possible, I would like to avoid `try/catch` statements.

Comment: Ho, do you notify errors?

Comment: You could also have `bar` return a dummy object instead of `this` in the case of a failure state. That dummy object may hold some failure information. (Although it must have all functions available for `i`, otherwise you may run into an exception trying to call a nonexistent function). You could also simply have `i` holding a failure state, and have functions do nothing in the case a previous operation has failed(or maybe do something different).

Comment: what do you meant by error occured?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee A hypothetical error that could include things such as a user not entering data into an input, a database failing to save, etc.

Comment: so, logical, and not code failure right?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so one straightforward thing is that **if you want to handle the case without `try/catch` you have to put if condition in your functions and obviously you have to return something, so that you can execute further functions on that context instead of exception**. So try creating all functionality in a object, and allow execution of your function logic only if someone extends. and on your failure return the base, otherwise return current object. In this was you can avoid creating objects every time.

Example:
Lets Consider You have `BaseService` where all functionalities are defined, and putting a Layer over it to just extend further, so you can go for this pattern:

```
foo: function() {
    if(<function foo does not belongs to this>) {
        .......
        .......
        if(<on logical failure>) {
            return this.__proto__;
        }
        .......
        .......
    }
    return this;
}
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
function BaseService() {
    var dataBucket = [13, 50, 45, 57, 95];

    this.foo = function() {
        if (Object.values(this).indexOf(arguments.callee) === -1) {
            console.log('processing foo');
        }
        return this;
    }
    this.bar = function() {
        if (Object.values(this).indexOf(arguments.callee) === -1) {
            console.log('processing bar');
        }
        return this;
    }
    this.processValIfExists = function(val) {
        if (Object.values(this).indexOf(arguments.callee) === -1) {
            console.log('processing processValIfExists');
            if (dataBucket.indexOf(val) > -1) {
                //process the value further
            } else {
                return this.__proto__;
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
};

//define the extended service, you can add further
//functionalities here. eg: createing the dataBucket here from args 
function WrapperService() {};

WrapperService.prototype = new BaseService(); // just extend from any service and use

var svc = new WrapperService();

console.log('----------Executes All-----------');
svc.foo().bar().processValIfExists(95).foo().bar();


console.log('----------Executes upto processValIfExists-----------');
svc.foo().bar().processValIfExists(100).foo().bar();
```

Note that its just a different approach that came to my mind, and to check for the current invoking method I tried to make the code generic instead of checking if its instance of `WrapperService` in a `BaseService` function in order to avoid code coupling and can be extend from any other Service as well.

Answer (score 1):

One could return a new empty instance of i, then on error return an empty obect:

```
class Chainable {
 constructor(data){
   this.data = data;
 }
 foo (foo) {
  //if an error occured
  if(foo == 10) return new Chainable();
  // Something here...
  return new Chainable(this.data + foo);
 },
 bar () {
  //if were in an error, fail silently
  if(!this.data) return this;
  // Something here...
  return this;
 }
}

(new Chainable(1))
  .foo(5).bar().bar().data // 6
(new Chainable(1))
  .foo(10).bar().bar().data //undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what you wanted, but Promises are great for chaining and for error handling:

```js
var i = {
   count: 0,
  foo: function () {
    // Something here...
    this.count++;
    console.log('foo');
    return  this.count < 4 ? 
      Promise.resolve(this) :
      Promise.reject(new Error('Count too high!'));
  },

  bar: function () {
    // Something here...
    this.count++;
    console.log('bar');
    return  this.count < 4 ? 
     Promise.resolve(this) :
        Promise.reject(new Error('Count too high! Count is ' + this.count));
  }
};


i.foo() // first
  .then(i => i.bar()) // second
  .then(i => i.foo()) // third
  .then(i => i.bar()) // too much!
  .then(i => i.whatIsThis()) // will not run
  .then(i => i.whatIsThis()) // will not run
  .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
```

Comment: No, really not. Promises should only be used for asynchronous results. A simple `try`/`catch` statement with synchronous exceptions would have been much easier here.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Could you point me to some resource that explains this in more detail? In my mind Promise may be a bit overkill here, but I don't see how its bad in the sense that it shouldn't be used.

Comment: No resources other than my experience :-) The problem with promises is not only that they are overkill (and the OP wanted a solution simpler! than `try`/`catch`), but that going asynchronous makes it impossible to go back. Don't do this when it's unnecessary. If you just like the chaining, an `Either` or `Maybe` datatype as found in many functional libraries would be the better choice.